# I can't find the adware to remove it

Tags: safari, security, google-chrome, malware

I have some pretty invasive adware going on right now. It is in both Safari and Chrome, so I don't believe it is an extension (I have also looked through all extensions). I have also tried searching for all the recommended adware agents found on the Apple Support Forum (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987). I have also looked at recent downloads and I can't find anything suspicious.

I am wondering if anyone can recommend some safe software to target the adware.

Comment: You are a bit vague on which adware you are actually fighting and which specific tools etc. you've already tried. Does the answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177019/does-my-air-have-malware-if-widows-pop-up-when-i-click-on-any-link help? If not, please provide more details about the specific adware you are facing.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. The problem was I followed other articles searching for known adware, and couldn't find it. So I didn't know what I was looking for! However, the link you posted helped my find a free and safe solution that found the adware. Thank You! and Thanks to AdwareMedic.com

Comment: did you check this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987

Comment: @Buscar웃 There is usually no reason to edit closed questions, unless you intent to have them reopened (which doesn't seem necessary in this case and given your edits). If you want to discuss this further, please ping any moderator in chat or create a question on the meta site.

Comment: @buscar see the comment by the OP (second comment above). The problem is solved for him.